# PHP/MongoDB: finding a nested object

Tags: php, mongodb, find

I am using the MongoDB driver for PHP and I need to find some nested elements. My structure looks like this:

```
 proce : { "type" : "cars" , "grupo" : { "_id" : "4e8478ace4b0dea06288ad63"}}
```

I need to get to the _id = 4e8478ace4b0dea06288ad63

I tried something like

```
$db->find( array( 'grupo._id' => "4e8478ace4b0dea06288ad63" ) );
```

but nothing happens..
thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your basic query looks correct.

However, that `grupo._id` looks like an `ObjectId`. Your query is attempting to match a string. Is that "4e84..." number a string or an ObjectId?

You may need to use the PHP [`MongoId`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mongoid.php) for matching.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was all to making it run =D